# Is there a DRY way to get n Cartesian Products in Python?

Tags: python

According to [72489951](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72490086/4162689), if one wants to generate the product of a list, this function does the job.

```
def generate_prods():
    from itertools import product
    in_list = ['a', 'b', 'c']
    out_prods = list(product(in_list, in_list))
    return out_prods
```

This returns

```
[('a', 'a'), ('a', 'b'), ('a', 'c'), ('b', 'a'), ('b', 'b'), ('b', 'c'), ('c', 'a'), ('c', 'b'), ('c', 'c')]
```

This is fine unless you want to add another character. Doing so means you need to hardcode another use of the same list.

```
def generate_prods():
    from itertools import product
    in_list = ['a', 'b', 'c']
    out_prods = list(product(in_list, in_list, in_list))
    return out_prods
```

Clearly, this is not DRY, so how do you generate the Cartesian Product for length *n* of the same list?

Answer (score -1):

The number of times to repeat the use of the same source list can be specified using `repeat`;

```
from itertools import product


def generate_prods(source_list: list, length: int):
    out_prods = list(product(source_list, repeat=length))
    return out_prods


test_list = ['a', 'b', 'c']
for prod_length in range(5):
    print(generate_prods(source_list=test_list,
                         length=prod_length))
```

Output:

```
[()]
[('a',), ('b',), ('c',)]
[('a', 'a'), ('a', 'b'), ('a', 'c'), ('b', 'a'), ('b', 'b'), ('b', 'c'), ('c', 'a'), ('c', 'b'), ('c', 'c')]
[('a', 'a', 'a'), ('a', 'a', 'b'), ('a', 'a', 'c'), ('a', 'b', 'a'), ('a', 'b', 'b'), ('a', 'b', 'c'), ('a', 'c', 'a'), ('a', 'c', 'b'), ('a', 'c', 'c'), ('b', 'a', 'a'), ('b', 'a', 'b'), ('b', 'a', 'c'), ('b', 'b', 'a'), ('b', 'b', 'b'), ('b', 'b', 'c'), ('b', 'c', 'a'), ('b', 'c', 'b'), ('b', 'c', 'c'), ('c', 'a', 'a'), ('c', 'a', 'b'), ('c', 'a', 'c'), ('c', 'b', 'a'), ('c', 'b', 'b'), ('c', 'b', 'c'), ('c', 'c', 'a'), ('c', 'c', 'b'), ('c', 'c', 'c')]
[('a', 'a', 'a', 'a'), ('a', 'a', 'a', 'b'), ('a', 'a', 'a', 'c'), ('a', 'a', 'b', 'a'), ('a', 'a', 'b', 'b'), ('a', 'a', 'b', 'c'), ('a', 'a', 'c', 'a'), ('a', 'a', 'c', 'b'), ('a', 'a', 'c', 'c'), ('a', 'b', 'a', 'a'), ('a', 'b', 'a', 'b'), ('a', 'b', 'a', 'c'), ('a', 'b', 'b', 'a'), ('a', 'b', 'b', 'b'), ('a', 'b', 'b', 'c'), ('a', 'b', 'c', 'a'), ('a', 'b', 'c', 'b'), ('a', 'b', 'c', 'c'), ('a', 'c', 'a', 'a'), ('a', 'c', 'a', 'b'), ('a', 'c', 'a', 'c'), ('a', 'c', 'b', 'a'), ('a', 'c', 'b', 'b'), ('a', 'c', 'b', 'c'), ('a', 'c', 'c', 'a'), ('a', 'c', 'c', 'b'), ('a', 'c', 'c', 'c'), ('b', 'a', 'a', 'a'), ('b', 'a', 'a', 'b'), ('b', 'a', 'a', 'c'), ('b', 'a', 'b', 'a'), ('b', 'a', 'b', 'b'), ('b', 'a', 'b', 'c'), ('b', 'a', 'c', 'a'), ('b', 'a', 'c', 'b'), ('b', 'a', 'c', 'c'), ('b', 'b', 'a', 'a'), ('b', 'b', 'a', 'b'), ('b', 'b', 'a', 'c'), ('b', 'b', 'b', 'a'), ('b', 'b', 'b', 'b'), ('b', 'b', 'b', 'c'), ('b', 'b', 'c', 'a'), ('b', 'b', 'c', 'b'), ('b', 'b', 'c', 'c'), ('b', 'c', 'a', 'a'), ('b', 'c', 'a', 'b'), ('b', 'c', 'a', 'c'), ('b', 'c', 'b', 'a'), ('b', 'c', 'b', 'b'), ('b', 'c', 'b', 'c'), ('b', 'c', 'c', 'a'), ('b', 'c', 'c', 'b'), ('b', 'c', 'c', 'c'), ('c', 'a', 'a', 'a'), ('c', 'a', 'a', 'b'), ('c', 'a', 'a', 'c'), ('c', 'a', 'b', 'a'), ('c', 'a', 'b', 'b'), ('c', 'a', 'b', 'c'), ('c', 'a', 'c', 'a'), ('c', 'a', 'c', 'b'), ('c', 'a', 'c', 'c'), ('c', 'b', 'a', 'a'), ('c', 'b', 'a', 'b'), ('c', 'b', 'a', 'c'), ('c', 'b', 'b', 'a'), ('c', 'b', 'b', 'b'), ('c', 'b', 'b', 'c'), ('c', 'b', 'c', 'a'), ('c', 'b', 'c', 'b'), ('c', 'b', 'c', 'c'), ('c', 'c', 'a', 'a'), ('c', 'c', 'a', 'b'), ('c', 'c', 'a', 'c'), ('c', 'c', 'b', 'a'), ('c', 'c', 'b', 'b'), ('c', 'c', 'b', 'c'), ('c', 'c', 'c', 'a'), ('c', 'c', 'c', 'b'), ('c', 'c', 'c', 'c')]
```

Comment: FWIW, the function `generate_prods` really doesn't add a lot here. Just `print(list(product(test_list, repeat=prod_length)))` reads pretty much the same…

Comment: True, however, this is just to demonstrate. In another application, one might want to do some stuff before `return`

Comment: Since you're just demonstrating the `repeat` parameter of `product`, such hypothetical other implementations are fairly irrelevant…